# FileResult throws System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm creating an endpoint that returning `File` download after it generates an Excel file, I have 2 methods, the first one is to return `FileStream` object as **asynchronous** and the second one is to return `File` download which called from `Http`.

Many said I have to make the stream `seek` to the beginning again before it's read by `FileResult`, but it seems doesn't work.

First method:

```
private async Task<FileStream> Generate(int projectId, DateTime period)
{
    ...
    if (...)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            ...
            return fs;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Second method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromBody]ReportFilter filter)
{
    FileStream fs = await Generate(filter.projectId, DateTime.Parse(filter.period));
    if (fs != null)
    {
        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return File(fs, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "kpi.xlsx");
    }

    return Json(new { status="error", message="Error while processing request" });
}
```

Unfortunately, it throws:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
   at System.IO.FileStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
```

[UPDATE]
Without `using` block:

```
private async Task<FileStream> Generate(int projectId, DateTime period)
{
    ...
    if (...)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        ISheet sheet1 = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");
        sheet1.AddMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 10));
        var rowIndex = 0;
        IRow row = sheet1.CreateRow(rowIndex);
        row.Height = 30 * 80;
        var cell = row.CreateCell(0);
        var font = workbook.CreateFont();
        font.IsBold = true;
        font.Color = HSSFColor.DarkBlue.Index2;
        cell.CellStyle.SetFont(font);

        cell.SetCellValue("A very long piece of text that I want to auto-fit innit, yeah. Although if it gets really, really long it'll probably start messing up more.");
        sheet1.AutoSizeColumn(0);
        rowIndex++;

        workbook.Write(fs);

        return fs;
    }

    return null;
}
```

[UPDATE]
Using jalsh's suggestion (by reopening the FileStream while preparing a download):

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    return File(fs, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "kpi.xlsx");
}
```

Comment: in your fs initialization set the `FileAcess` to `ReadWrite`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: debug and make sure that the application is _actually_ rebuilding, is it failing on the seek method? or on the return call?

Comment: Yes Im sure, it's been rebuilt. It's failing on `Seek()` line, but if I remove the `Seek()` call, it's failing on the `return` call.

Comment: try to remove `workbook.Write(fs);` call, I'm starting to believe that this is the culprit

Comment: Yeah it works, but without that, it seems useless. Is there another way?

Comment: the issue is with whatever library your using, it's closing the file on the `Write` call, I'd suggest you either change the library (if possible) or just reopen the file after that

Comment: Ohh I see, I updated the question with the way you suggested. But the `fs` object becomes `undisposed` after it returns the File.

Comment: Nobody ever reads exception messages :( `Cannot access a closed file` means that your code tryes to access a closed file. You already close (dispose) it when you returning from `Generate` method, so you should never try to use it now. Why do you ever need a stream? Why not to return a `byte[]` instead?

Comment: @JustinusHermawan don't instantiate a `FileStream`, all you need is a `File` object..

Comment: Assuming this is ASP.NET MVC (not Core), you don't need to wrap the stream in a using statement - FileStreamResult already does that for you ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/FileStreamResult.cs)), so it will dispose of the stream when the response is completed.

Comment: @jalsh I use this instead: `return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "kpi.xlsx");`, is it fine?

Answer (score 0):

The using statement calls `dispose()` at the end of its scope. see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) link, it has a case just like yours...

you could either not use the using statement and dispose of the object manually whenever you're done with it. Or you could just reopen the filestream again, or maybe return a `File` Instance from your method that you could reopen the stream with

Now that you shared your full code, it seems to me that your `Write` call is disposing the FileStream or closing it, you can try reopen the filestream just after you do the Write() call.

Comment: I did without `using` statement previously, but with no luck.

Comment: you're not using the `using` statement and not calling `dispose()` but you still get the exception??

Comment: please share the code without the using statement and the exception in that case

Comment: Yes, I did it just like this: `FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)`, without `using` block, but still produces the same.

Comment: and you didn't call `fs.dispose()`? but you get an exception on the `Seek` call?

Comment: Updated my question just now with *without using block*  version.

Answer (score 0):

Often when you want to use a disposable object like this it is better to inject in the action required, rather that to expose the disposable object outside of the method that creates it.

I've simplified your code down, but this is the basic idea:

```
private async Task Generate(int projectId, DateTime period, Action<FileStream> operation)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        operation(fs);
    }
}
```

Now you call it like this:

```
public async Task Index(int projectId, string period)
{
    await Generate(projectId, DateTime.Parse(period), fs =>
    {
        if (fs != null)
        {
            fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(fs, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "kpi.xlsx");
        }
    });
}
```

This allows `operation(fs)` to complete before the end of the `using` statement.

Comment: The issue isn't with his `using`, he tried removing it and it still fails

Comment: @jalsh - The issue is that he is disposing of an object somewhere before he's using the stream. If he can inject the stream then the problem may be solved. I still feel that this is a viable solution. The OP should provide a [mcve] to be able to confirm.

Comment: Agree, same goes for my first answer, but that wasn't the case

Comment: @jalsh - Then the OP needs to provide a [mcve] so that we can diagnose.